# Definite article before proper nouns?

Tags: word-usage, articles

I have my page and my mobile number is shown there. 
Which one is correct ?

> You can contact me through the Viber or WhatsApp.

or

> You can contact me through Viber or WhatsApp.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You don't need the "the" before Viber.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the article "the" with proper nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93457/use-of-the-article-the-with-proper-nouns)

Answer (score 2):

In English, we hardly ever put an article before a proper name. Those are proper names, so an article is not appropriate.