# When describing a whole species of animal, is it correct to omit the article?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from an article at [Testbig](https://www.testbig.com/integrated-toefl-writing-essays/archaeologists-have-recently-found-fossil-150-million-year-old):

> Archaeologists have recently found a fossil of a 150-million-year-old
> mammal known as Repenornamus robustus (R. robustus). Interestingly,
> the mammal's stomach contained the remains of a psittacosaur dinosaur.
> Some researchers have therefore suggested that R. robustus was an
> active hunter of dinosaurs. However, a closer analysis has made the
> hypothesis that R. robustus was an active hunter unlikely. It was
> probably just a scavenger that sometimes fed on dinosaur eggs
> containing unhatched dinosaurs.

When describing an animal species as a whole, we say "a dog is", "the dog is", "dogs are". Why does the passage above use simply "R.robustus was"?

Comment: *R. robustus* is a proper noun. *Dog* is not.

Comment: Please quote the text, don't post a picture. This is very annoying for blind people.

Comment: An article is not used with the Latin name of a species.

Comment: A smith is hard to find nowadays [which is inconvenient when your horse needs reshoeing] / The smith was once a key worker in the village / I know John Smith. // A gorilla is a formidable animal / The gorilla is protected in certain areas /  Gorilla gorilla gorilla is listed as a _Critically Endangered_ subspecies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definite article before proper nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420964/definite-article-before-proper-nouns)

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, when biologists and paleontologists refer to a species by its formal, Latin name, they treat it like a proper noun (capitalizing the genus), so no article is used with it. And even though it refers to a group of animals/plants, it's usually conjugated as a singular noun.

So we say "dogs *are* man's best friend" but "Canis familiaris *is* Homo sapiens's best friend".